# Como se puede poner un valor de la tabla en una variable para luego sea utilizada en un href

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, bootstrap, variables

Le he estado dando vueltas a este problema, yo tengo una tabla que contiene un `id`, nombre,  una imagen guardada en ruta, y una `dirección php`.

Estos datos están ordenados mediante `divs` que forman una caja y cada linea en la tabla es una caja más que se muestra en la pagina, y los datos los muestro de forma dinámica de esta forma.

```
<?php print($img['id']); ?>

<?php print($img['direccion']); ?>
```

Entonces en cada una de las cajas se encuentra un botón, que me gustaría enlazar `direccion` con el href.
Pongamos un ejemplo, yo en la linea 1 de mi tabla se encuentra esta información.

```
id--> 1
Nombre--> Juan
direccion--> paginajuan.php
```

Como puedo yo enlazar `direccion` con el href de forma dinámica que al aparecer lo datos en caja uno yo le pueda dar al botón y me dirige a `paginajuan.php` Esa pagina estará creada ya en el servidor.

He probado con esto que abre todos los valores y los almacena de alguna forma decirlo en la variable `$img`, lo que pasa que cuando pongo esta variable con `direccion` (lo podéis ver arriba) en el href del botón me sale error.

```html
$SQLStatement = $this->DBConexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
        $SQLStatement->execute();
    

            
        while($img = $SQLStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

El $img lo uso porque hay una imagen en uno de los campos.
La `direccion` esta guardado en un campo `VARCHAR (255)`.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es generar un boton o link de la siguiente manera haciendo un 'echo' dentro del href de tu link 'a' por cada uno de los registros de la tabla que se va imprimiendo en pantalla: <a href="<?php echo $img['direccion'] ?>">Link</a>

Comment: Eres un maestro, esa es la solución, eso si ahora se le quiere dar estilo se abre un <style> y se le da. Gracias, se lo dejo a usted @francofernandez si quiere escribir una respuesta le daré el tick verde.

Comment: si desea iniciarte en php te recomendaría un framework básico como https://github.com/arcanisgk/Last-Hammer esta en desarrollo por lo tanto puedes colaborar y aprender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publico la solución al problema que le funciono a @JackMore para cerrar la pregunta.
Lo que se me ocurrió es generar un boton o link de la siguiente manera, haciendo un 'echo' de la variable donde se almacena la dirección dentro del href de tu link 'a' por cada uno de los registros de la tabla que se va imprimiendo en pantalla:

```
<a href="<?php echo $img['direccion']; ?>">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

si esta es el `href` guardado en una tabla:

```
$img['direccion'] //Path de la imagen  /root/imagenes/img.jpg
$img['id'] //id de la imagen  texto de referencia visual o otro dato.
```

entonces debes hacer lo siguiente `concatenar`:

```
$linkImagen = '<a href="'.$img['direccion'].'">'.$img['id'].' otro Texto</a>';
```

puedes imprimirlo con desde php directamente:

```
echo $linkImagen;
```

o si tienes una plantilla `HTML` dentro de un archivo con extencion `.php` puedes imprimirlo dee manera incrustada así:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <?=$linkImagen?>
</div>
```

Para aplicar un estilo puedes trabar con clases:

```
 $linkImagen = '<a class="estilo1 estilo2 estilo3" href="'.$img['direccion'].'">'.$img['id'].' otro Texto</a>';
```